# Array.filter() returns different results

Tags: javascript

So, I have this function in my code:

```
filterByWeek(data) {
    //  so just like with the days, here we want to get a limited amount of data (last 6 weeks or less);
    const weeksAgo6 = moment().startOf('week').subtract(6, 'weeks').toDate();
    console.log('data', data);
    const filteredData = data.filter((item) => moment(item.date).isAfter(weeksAgo6));
    console.log('filter test1', data.filter((item) => moment(item.date).isAfter(weeksAgo6)));
    console.log('filter test2', filteredData);

    return filteredData;
  }
```

and the data argument is an array with objects that look like this:

```
{
  date: "2019-07-21T14:03:37.759Z",
  _id: "5d3b29e7e7e5db358c4ec482",
  exercise: "5d35da3142c6445078cd03f2",
  oneRM: 93
}
```

of all the objects in this array I want to filter the ones out with a date that's sooner than 6 weeks ago. I do this with the Array.filter() function. And based on console.log `filter test 1`it should work. But then I try to console.log `filter test 2` and it returns an empty array. Does someone know what might be causing that?

**result console.log `filter test 1`: the results I expected**

```
[{
  "date": "2019-07-20T14:03:37.759Z",
  "_id": "5d3b0876e7e5db358c4ec47b",
  "exercise": "5d35da3142c6445078cd03f2",
  "oneRM": 86
},
{
  "date": "2019-07-21T14:03:37.759Z",
  "_id": "5d3b29e7e7e5db358c4ec482",
  "exercise": "5d35da3142c6445078cd03f2",
  "oneRM": 93
},
{
  "date": "2019-07-24T14:03:37.759Z",
  "_id": "5d3b3896e7e5db358c4ec48b",
  "exercise": "5d35da3142c6445078cd03f2",
  "oneRM": 89
}]
```

**Result console.log `filter test 2`: An empty array even though I thought I logged the same thing**

[image]

Comment: Provide a working fiddle. Also try logging it before the second call to see what it contains.

Comment: Try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. What are the chances `data` is changing in the background though?

Comment: Your code works as is https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bird-49j4q

Comment: Just a small advice - it is better to break long lines - it makes the code easier to read.